# Drupal 7 views and content api

Tags: drupal-7, view

I'm using Content API for Drupal or Views 3 to return some data from Drupal 7.

Problem I am facing is with Content API, the documentation says to use query parameter **fields[]=[field_name]** to display just data for those fields instead of displaying all data.

That didn't work for me, when I tried to query it with content api like so:

```
http://wawineregions.com.au/wawineregions/contentapi/content?type=winery&fields[]=field_rating&sort=title&page=0
```

It doesn't display my "field_rating" field in the REST endpoint which I am expecting it to.

As for my Views, I am using Views 3. I have setup a new view and it returns the correct result in the REST endpoint if I only have say the built in field "title". As soon as I include one of my custom field such as the "field_rating", the REST endpoint returns me ALL data for ALL fields, which isn't what I want.

Example:

```
http://wawineregions.com.au/wawineregions/rest/views/view_wineriesbasic
```

I just want it to return my data for the two fields I told it to display, the title and the rating. Not all the other data attached with it.

I am using:

```
Drupal 7
Services 3.x
Views 3.x
Content API 7.x-3.3-apha
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why do you post it here, and not  on [drupal.stackexchange.com](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: HA! What do they know about drupal?

Comment: I've done it on both, hoping there would some Drupal devs here that may know.